# Colocar tema dinâmico PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho dois templates no meu projeto web.
Quero usar um tema do PrimeFaces diferente para cada template.

Como faço isso?

No `web.xml`, quando eu coloco o tema do PrimeFaces muda para todos templates, mas quero que cada template tenha um tema.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808823/primefaces-how-to-make-the-theme-dynamic)

Comment: @Douglas

Ele diz  que preciso de um bean que retornará o nome do tema como uma string, porém não sei como fazer isso poderia me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer todo esse trâmite no `ManagedBean`. Por exemplo:

---

UsuarioMB:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UsuarioMB {

    private String templateSelecionado = "templateDefault.css";
    private String temaSelecionado = "temaDoTemplateDefault";
    private List<String> temasDisponiveis = new ArrayList<String>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if(condicao) { //condição para trocar de tema/template
            templateSelecionado = "templateDiferente.css";
            temaSelecionado = "temaDoTemplateDiferente";
        }
        //Populando os temas
        temasDisponiveis.add("casablanca");
        temasDisponiveis.add("cupertino");
        temasDisponiveis.add("bluesky");
    }

    //getters & setters
}
```

---

template.xhtml

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="#{usuarioMB.templateSelecionado}" />
```

---

paginaParaEscolherTema.xhtml

```
<p:themeSwitcher value="#{usuarioMB.temaSelecionado}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{usuarioMB.temasDisponiveis}" />
</p:themeSwitcher>
```

---

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>#{usuarioMB.temaSelecionado}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

---

**Explicação**:

Através dos atributos `templateSelecionado` e `temaSelecionado`, ambos do tipo `String`, é possível modificar tanto o css quanto o tema do PrimeFaces de forma dinâmica.

Basta fazer com que a tag `<h:outputStylesheet>` use o atributo `templateSelecionado` e fazer com que a página que altere o tema (que contenha o componente `<p:themeSwitcher>`) e o `web.xml` usem o atributo `temaSelecionado`.

Comment: Igor,

excelente explicação e domínio no assunto,

é um projeto para faculdade estou estudando para tentar desenvolver

pelo q eu vi no seu post, me parece q vai ser o usuario que vai alterar o tema certo ?

eu gostaria por exemplo q na tela de Tutor fosse o tema south street e no da clinica fosse o Cupertino

obrigado pela ajuda desde já amigo

Comment: Legal que gostou! Obrigado :-) Funcionou?

Comment: Entendi. Você pode usar um `ManagedBean` `ApplicationScoped` só para definir o tema e o template e ao carregar as páginas de Tutor e Clinica, faça com que eles alterem os atributos nesse `ManagedBean`.

Comment: Beleza, vou tentar seguir sua dica !

Obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: Legal! Estou indo pra faculdade agora. Caso não consiga, comente aqui que de noite faço um código e coloco no github, blz?

Comment: Poxa Igor valeu mesmo cara pela ajuda !!!

estou prototipando as telas primeiro ainda vou tentar nessa semana mesmo, vou fazer o teste quando estiver utilizando um BD para fazer esse controle no momento de login

se for tutor abre um menu ( template) com o tema south street se for clinica abre com cupertino !

é um sistema de clinica animal bem legal a ideia 

fiz um projeto no netbeans fiz o lance de tema tbm mais foi bem mais facil pois era sistema desktop neah kkkkk

WEB to apanhando ainda porem quero aprender sempre q possivel :-)

valeu e boa aula !